# Error when calling a function having a record with float fields as an arg using `function:call` method

Tags: ballerina, dynamic-function, ballerina-swan-lake

```ballerina
isolated function mockFunction(record {|string operation; float operand1; float operand2;|} input) returns string{
    return "mockFunction scuccessful";
}

public function main() returns error? {
    string input = "{\"operation\":\"ADDITION\",\"operand1\":23.0,\"operand2\":43.0}";
    map<json> & readonly inputJson = check input.fromJsonStringWithType();
    any|error observation = function:call(mockFunction, inputJson);
    io:println(observation);
}
```

I got the following error when I tried the above.

```ballerina
error: {ballerina/lang.function}IncompatibleArguments {"message":"arguments of incompatible types: argument list '(map<(json & readonly)> & readonly)' cannot be passed to function expecting parameter list '(ai.agent:record {| string operation; float operand1; float operand2; |})'"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function:call()` method will attempt to cast the `inputJson` to the expected argument type. It gives the above error when the casting fails.

`fromJsonStringWithType` https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0#fromJsonStringWithType is a combination of `fromJsonString` and `fromJsonWithType`. Numbers are generally converted to decimal with `fromJsonString` https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0#fromJsonString.

> Numbers in the JSON string are converted into Ballerina values of type
> decimal except in the following two cases: if the JSON number starts
> with - and is numerically equal to zero, then it is converted into
> float value of -0.0; otherwise, if the JSON number is syntactically an
> integer and is in the range representable by a Ballerina int, then it
> is converted into a Ballerina int. A JSON number is considered
> syntactically an integer if it contains neither a decimal point nor an
> exponent.

Therefore, in this case, `operand1` and `operand2` are `decimal` and not `float`.  This is why the cast fails.

```ballerina
io:println(inputJson is record {|string operation; float operand1; float operand2;|}); // false
io:println(inputJson is record {|string operation; decimal operand1; decimal operand2;|}); // true
```

The solution is to provide the exact type when doing the `fromJsonStringWithType`

```ballerina
record {|string operation; float operand1; float operand2;|} inputRecord = check input.fromJsonStringWithType();
```

`fromJsonStringWithType` will creates a new value doing the numeric conversions, not a cast. Here the `fromJsonString` step will still result in `decimal` values for these fields, but the `fromJsonWithType` step will handle the numeric conversion when cloning.